# После софтварной перезагрузки зависает ESP32 в коде инициализации HardwareSerial

Tags: serial, esp32, arduino-ide

Работаю в ArduinoIDE с ESP32 и датчиком отпечатка пальцев TFP625A. Датчик висит на UART2 и обслуживается библиотекой [FPM](https://github.com/brianrho/FPM) с помощью `HardwareSerial`. Всё работает хорошо до того момента, пока программно не будет выполнена перезагрузка - `ESP.restart()`. После этой команды микроконтроллер перезагружается и зависает в месте инициализации датчика. Я вставил печать в файл `HardwareSerial` и увидел, что в функции `HardwareSerial::begin(...)` код не проходит дальше этого места

```
_uart = uartBegin(_uart_nr, baud ? baud : 9600, config, rxPin, txPin, 256, invert);
```

Как я понимаю, после перезагрузки микроконтроллера в его регистрах остаётся информация о настроенном ранее `UART2`.
Попытки обнулить UART перед перезагрузкой микроконтроллера не исправляют ситуацию. Если же перезагрузить микроконтроллер кнопкой перезагрузки, то всё работает нормально.

Как побороть зависание ESP32?

Фрагменты кода:

```
HardwareSerial mySerial(2);
FPM fpm(&mySerial);
...
void freeFPM()
{
    fpm = 0;
    mySerial.end();
    mySerial = 0;
}

bool fpm_setup()
{
    freeFPM();
    mySerial = HardwareSerial(2);
    finger = FPM(&mySerial);
    mySerial.begin(57600);
    fpm.begin(0);
}

void restartESP()
{
    freeFPM();
    ESP.restart();
}
```

Comment: Видимо `ESP.restart()` не все сбрасывает. Сделать сброс через сторожевой таймер или дернуть пин резета любым портом - не подходит?

Comment: Сторожевым таймером не помогает - та же ситуация происходит. А вот дёрнуть ногой помогает, но при рестарте нога остаётся в низком состоянии и процессор постоянно перегружается